# Raw query in Prisma Query Console

Tags: prisma

I'm trying to run a raw query in the Prisma Query Console of the Data Platform.

The line

```js
await prisma.$queryRaw(Prisma.sql`SELECT * FROM "public"."User";`)
```

Returns a `PrismaClientUnknownRequestError` error with the message

> `$queryRaw` is a tag function, please use it like the following:
>
> `` const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = ${1} OR email = ${'user@email.com'}; ``
>
> Or read our docs at https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw

If instead I replace it by the following as suggested by the message

```js
await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM "public"."User";`
```

The code is greyed and the execute button is disabled so I can't run the query.

[image: execution disabled]

How can I run raw queries in the Query Console?

Comment: Hello! You will need to create a ticket in Prisma Data Platform as your question is related to that. You can do so by following instructions here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/data-platform/contact-support

Comment: @HarshitPant thanks for the suggestion. I've contacted the support to help find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now (nov. 2022) this is a **known limitation** of the Query Console. Here is the answer from Prisma support:

> The format of `$queryRaw` without parenthesis isn't supported yet, due to which the execution is disabled.
> The error that is returned suggests defining variables and passing them in $queryRaw in tagged literal format, as of now defining variables in Query Console isn't supported either. Our product team is aware of this limitation, and we do plan to address this.

The **workaround** is to use `$queryRawUnsafe`. The syntax is

```js
await prisma.$queryRawUnsafe('SELECT * FROM "public"."User"')
```